# Side Channel Analysis (CorrPA), comparison between HW-results and measured power traces

Tags: side-channel-attack, dpa

I think I have missed something very fundamental.

I am trying to understand the step in DPA where you compare your hypothetical power consumptions with your measured ones.
The Matrix **H** with Matrix **T**.

Matrix **T** is of size *D x T*, where D is the number of data blocks and T is the number of measured points in one power trace. This implies that an element value in this matrix **T** can be of 0.58W (just an example).

If I use Hamming Weight, as power model, I will end up with a real number.
E.g., 0110 0111 = 5 (dimensionless). How can this number correlate with the power traces that are in Watts? (e.g., If I use Pearsons).

Comment: To hopefully attract more answers, would you mind adding / linking to an example paper / ressource of DPA so people can get started on reference hunting or whatever?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the value you found (in watt). Try to have a look at [this](https://hitcon.org/2015/ENT/PDF/Power%20Analysis%20Attacks_JP,%20YH.pdf)  file, it's really well explained in my opinion. If you look for page 21 for instance, you'll see that the plaintext produces a certain waveform; then, after the hypotesis and the S-Box output, the correlation is clearly done with the power model obtained and the value of the traces (page 23)